# replace "," with "." in xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file that I want to import in my opencart store.

My XML file is:

> 

```
<Model>100002</Model>   
<Itemcode>10000200</Itemcode>   
<Description>description of item</Description>   
<Currency>EUR</Currency>   
<IndustryCol1>5,98</IndustryCol1>   
<IndustryCol2>2,88</IndustryCol2>   
<IndustryCol3>2,8</IndustryCol3>
<IndustryCol4>2,7</IndustryCol4>
</PriceInfoRow>
</PriceInfo>
```

I need to replace comma with dot in

```
<IndustryCol1>5,98</IndustryCol1>   
<IndustryCol2>2,88</IndustryCol2>   
<IndustryCol3>2,8</IndustryCol3>
<IndustryCol4>2,7</IndustryCol4>
```

I need this because when I load the XML file with comma the script turns 5,98 to 5,00.

Any help?

Edit:

This is the function when i upload a xml file:

> private function importXML($filename, $product_tag, $xml_options) {
>         $this->product_tag = $product_tag;      $this->xml_data = '';       $fh =
>   fopen($filename, 'r');        $xml_parser =
>   xml_parser_create($this->file_encoding);      xml_set_object($xml_parser,
>   $this);       xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, 'startTag', 'endTag');
>         xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, 'cData');
>         xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
>         while ($data = fread($fh, 4096)) {          if (!xml_parse($xml_parser,
>   $data, feof($fh))) {
>                 xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
>                 return false;           }           if ($this->cron_fetch && $this->total_items_ready >= CRON_FETCH_NUM)            {
>                 xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
>                 return true;            }       }       xml_parser_free($xml_parser);       return true;    }

Comment: Are you asking the whole or the part ? share your code where you get value like `5,98` ?

Comment: Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) for each number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get help *for your code*, you must first show us you coding attempt to solve your problem. In this site, people won't code for you (you can search for someone to hire, though), you will only get help to improve your existing code or to solve a specific coding question (for example, "what is the difference between these 2 functions?").

Comment: Its from total import module private function cleanPrice($raw_price) {
  $leading_decimal = strpos($raw_price, '.');
  if ($leading_decimal !== false && $leading_decimal === 0) {
   $raw_price = '0' . $raw_price;
  }
  $raw_price = preg_replace('/^[^\d.]+/', '', $raw_price);
  $raw_price = str_replace(',', '', $raw_price);
  return $raw_price;
 }  i have tried to comment it but same problem.

Comment: please edit your code with these details, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($s);
// Find all items which name starts with "IndustryCol" 
$items = $xml->xpath('//*[starts-with(name(), "IndustryCol")]');

foreach($items as $k=>$v) {
  // Replace node values 
  $items[$k][0] = str_replace(',', '.', $v);
} 

echo $xml->asXML();
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/931465)

Comment: $this->xml_data = str_replace(",", ".", $this->xml_data); works but it changes "," to "." in all fields. I need it to change only to IndustryCol1 - 4

Comment: $items contain only field IndustryCol1, IndustryCol2... Print_r($items) to watch

Comment: can you be more specific ho to insert $items contain only in 
 
$this->xml_data = str_replace(",", ".", $this->xml_data);

Comment: at start of my code `xml = simplexml_load_string($this->xml_data);` and  after all  `$this->xml_data = $xml->asXML();`

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<'

Comment: and also this error    Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on boolean

Comment: This means your $this->xml_data is not corect xml